# Cannot register an existing user in app1

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

The user has an account with email/password in the application nr1.

Steps:
New user registration in the application nr2.
Use the same email/password as in application nr1.

Proposal: Check before registering if the user exists in auth if this is allowed by the sdk. If it is not allowed, login is tried instead of the register, and if successful, a new document is created with the admin data.

```
 Future<bool> registerOrLoginUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String name,
    required String phone,
  }) async {
    try {
      emit(const RegisterState(status: RegisterStatus.submitting));
      print('1');
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
      print('2');
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      print('3');
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("admin_users").doc(user.user?.uid).set({
        "email": email,
        "uid": user.user?.uid,
        "name": name,
        "phoneNumber": phone,
        "role": UserRole.notVerified.toSimpleString(),
      });
      print('4');
      emit(const RegisterState(status: RegisterStatus.success));
      return true;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('5');
      debugPrint("Auth failed $e");
      register(email: email, password: password, name: name, phone: phone);
      return false;
    }
  }
```